# Поиск по своему коду

Tags: git, pycharm, ide, clion, grep

Можно ли в IDE от Jetbrains выполнять поиск по коду, который закоммитил человек с определённым именем (я)? Если нет, то как это сделать вручную в `git`? Необходима поддержка регулярок в поиске.

Comment: `git log --author="AlexGlebe"`

Comment: @AlexGlebe мне нужен поиск по коду, `git log --author kyle -p | grep 42` неудобно использовать и коммит с файлом не всегда видны

Comment: `$ git log --author kyle -p | less` — и дальше поиском находите нужное. да, программа less умеет в те же самые регулярные выражения, что доступны в вашей (надеюсь, нормальной, а не от каких-нибудь там ms или apple) операционной системе: [The pattern is a regular expression, as recognized by the regular expression library supplied by your system.](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/less.1.html)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin это работает, но проблема в том, что очень много мусорного вывода. Например, я хочу найти только код, где я объявил переменную `int x;`, коммит и файл с номером строки + опционально контекст небольшой объявления этого, а ваша команда выводит мне полностью текст диффа, который может быть очень большим, т.к. есть другие изменения

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin мб в `less` есть что-то вроде next occurence of pattern, чтобы можно было только по ним ходить?

Comment: да, вам срочно надо почитать `$ man less` (ну или примерно то же самое по ссылке выше). продолжить поиск — `n`. // p.s. кстати, вы далеко не одиноки: о том, что программа *less* умеет в поиск, вероятно, не знают многие её пользователи.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin верно, но нашёл более серьёзную проблему. Смотрите, мне нужны только мною изменённые строки, а эта команда может (и выдала) дифф коммита для файла, который я менял + в котором есть паттерн, но именно паттерн не я менял! Т.е. я делал коммит в этот файл, поэтому он появляется, там есть контекст у строки, которую я поменял, а в этом контексте есть паттерн, но этот паттерн не я менял, т.е. ненужный мне результат. Надо чтобы паттерн был именно в символах, что я поменял. Мб профильтровать паттерн для строк диффа с + и -?

Comment: смотрите: вам надо не только о программе *less* почитать, но и о программе *git* вообще и программе *diff* (ею используемой) в частности. можете начать хоть с [википедийной статьи](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff#%D0%A3%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82) по поводу «универсального формата» (unified format), в который умеет и программа *diff* (и кототрый по умолчанию используется и программой *git* в тех местах, где она программу *diff* применяет). // в частности, узнаете, что же означают `+` и `-` в начале строки.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin ну понятно, надо ковыряться в передаваемых параметрах, чтобы формат был без контекста, например. Неужели этот довольно очевидный юз кейс не сделали в IDEшках или как сабкоманду гита?

Comment: да не надо вам в параметрах копаться. запустили `git log -p ...` и ищете что вам надо. например, `^\+[^+]*int x;` // вы озвучили, кстати, очень редко (в моей личной практике — вообще никогда не) используемый «юз кейс».

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin согласен, так проще даже